# How to safely copy structs with members pointing to other nested members in C++

Tags: c++, c++20

Consider these structs that come from an **external library** (I can't edit it)

```cpp
struct Color;
struct Tires;
struct CarEF { // a car's external features
    Color* pColor;
    Tires* pTires;
};
```

Now, in **my codebase**, I want to use these structs and pass them to a factory-function that utilizes this struct to call a bunch of library constructors and create the `Car` (and dependent) objects. To consolidate all the info, I made this struct.

```
struct CarInfo { // captures all info needed to create 'Car'
    Color color{};
    Tires {};
    CarEF car_ef{};
    // other items
};

CarInfo create_car_info() {
    CarInfo info {
        .color = { /*  */ },
        .tires = { /*  */ },
        .car_ef = {
            .pColor = &info.color;
            .pTires = &info.tires;
        }
    };
    return info;
}

// factory function
Car carfactory(CarInfo) { 
    // create tire, create color ... etc (library code)
    // call Car-ctor with the above (library code)
}
```

```
CarInfo create_info = create_car_info(); // assume copy
```

The pointers in the `CarInfo` always point to other initialized members in the same struct instance.

Now, I'm afraid that the pointers might become invalid after the struct is copied. Sure, copy-elision could save me (**will it?**), but the question is, **how do I safely copy this struct**, so that the pointers in the `create_info` point to the correct items?

```
 info (local 
 stack variable 
 destroyed)              create_info (copied)
+----------------+     +----------------+
|                |     |                |
| +--->.color  <-+-----+-+    .color    |
| |              |     | |              |
| |              |     | |              |
| | +->.tyre  <--+-----+-+-+  .tyre     |
| | |            |     | | |            |
| | |            |     | | |            |
| | |  .car      |     | | |  .car      |
| +-+----.pColor |     | +-+----.pColor |
|   |            |     |   |            |
|   +----.pTyre  |     |   +----.pTyre  |
|                |     |                |
+----------------+     +----------------+
```

Comment: This seems like a very peculiar design. But if you insist on it, you need to implement your own copy constructor and copy assignment operator. See [The rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). This might be a case where you need every special member *except* a destructor.

Comment: So I basically need to "deep-copy" pointer elements, and then return the newly created object, correct? Please feel free to suggest an alternative method (maybe a pastebin that I'll read, or some other communication medium, if you think that might be irrelevant to answer the question, and if you're okay with it?)

Comment: Well it seems like the members of your `Car` point to other members of the object that owns the `Car`. So there isn't really a deep copy needed. You just need, for every copy, to set the pointers to the members of the new instance. Edit : it isn't clear to me what `CarInfo::car` is contributing. Are you sure you need it?

Comment: So I copy the first 2 members and then repoint the pointers before return from the copy function, correct?

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you mean by "copy function". To be clear, you have to do thins in a [Copy Constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor). If you try it in some sort of factory function that makes copies, you will be back to square one.

Comment: I mean copy-constructor or the copy-assignment-operator, apologies, should've been clear.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux >it isn't clear to me what CarInfo::car is contributing. 
Well it is a small replica of the library I've seen. It doesn't take the Car directly. I'll update the question, a few minutes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232967/discussion-between-b-dex-float-and-francois-andrieux).

Answer (score 1):

In your current code, `create_car_info` returns a named local variable. The compiler is allowed, but not required to omit the move- or copy-construction when returning the `CarInfo`. This is called [named return value optimization (NRVO)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)

With C++17 and 20, you would have a guarantee that no copy or move takes place *if you were returning a pr-value*, like this ([cpp reference page on this topic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)):

```cpp
CarInfo create_car_info() {
    // assuming there is a ctor which will set up car_ef to point to the right addresses.
    return CarInfo({/* color */}, {/* tires */});
}
```

Your `carfactory` takes a `CarInfo` by value, so here, a copy is made. You could use a const reference to prevent the copy.

However, from a software architectural point, I would advise against relying on this. If at any point, anyone decides to change `create_car_info` just a tiny bit, it will badly break.

It seems like your only motivation to add a custom copy-constructor here is to make sure the pointers are still correct after the copy operation. From the [rule of zero as stated on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three):

> Classes that have custom destructors, copy/move constructors or copy/move assignment operators should deal exclusively with ownership (which follows from the Single Responsibility Principle).

So, what I'd suggest you to do, instead, is to find a way you do not have to worry about your pointers, even after passing your `CarInfo` by value. I can think of two ways to achieve that:

1. Passing around your `CarInfo` object by pointer, most likely as smart-pointer, to ensure that the object is not moved in memory and its internal pointers stay valid for its whole lifetime. Then, it wouldn't need to be copied when passing it to functions.
2. Simply adding a member function to your `CarInfo` struct that gives you the correct pointers for its current location in memory. Even if the object is passed by value, and thus a copy is made, and the code using it asks its copy for the pointers, it will get back correct pointers.

Would any of these approaches work for you? If not: Why?

Comment: In the code-snippet, info is undefined (`&info.color`), correct? But yes I get your point. Wanted to know if there was a to refer to members in a `pr-value` (damn gotta learn up on these things!). You've given me a lot to think about, I'll get back, thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: @B_Dex_Float That is correct, I didn't consider the self-pointer there. I changed it to a more generic variant using a imaginary constructor that initializes everything correctly.